# FSEvents mysteriously fails to deliver events in some folders

Tags: cocoa, macos, fsevents

this is killing me, and I'm not sure I know how to approach debugging it.

I'm using Mac FSEvents API to monitor a given folder on the file system. However, occasionally, some folders stop sending any notification events. So far, this has only happened for folders inside ~/Dropbox, and has affected just a few users of my app (and also regularly affects me as well).

The crazy part is that the way to 'cure' the file system is to do:

```
mv ~/Dropbox/some/stuck/folder ~/Dropbox/some/stuck/folder.0
mkdir ~/Dropbox/some/stuck/folder
mv ~/Dropbox/some/stuck/folder.0/* ~/Dropbox/some/stuck/folder/
rmdir ~/Dropbox/some/stuck/folder.0
```

After running these commands, the folder gets unstuck and starts sending events! It takes a few tries to find which of the parent folders is the culprit, but it's always some folder inside Dropbox. (Quitting Dropbox or rebooting does not cure it.)

I'm doing nothing special in my code. Monitoring is started using:

```
FSEventStreamContext context;
context.version = 0;
context.info = self;
context.retain = NULL;
context.release = NULL;
context.copyDescription = NULL;

_streamRef = FSEventStreamCreate(nil,
                                 (FSEventStreamCallback)FSMonitorEventStreamCallback,
                                 &context,
                                 (CFArrayRef)paths,
                                 kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                 0.25,
                                 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes);
if (!_streamRef) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to start monitoring of %@ (FSEventStreamCreate error)", _path);
}

FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(_streamRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
if (!FSEventStreamStart(_streamRef)) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to start monitoring of %@ (FSEventStreamStart error)", _path);
}
```

and the callback looks like this (not that it matters):

```
static void FSMonitorEventStreamCallback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef, FSMonitor *monitor, size_t numEvents, NSArray *eventPaths, const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[], const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numEvents; i++) {
        NSString *path = [eventPaths objectAtIndex:i];
        FSEventStreamEventFlags flags = eventFlags[i];
        [monitor sendChangeEventWithPath:path flags:flags];
    }
}
```

Happens on both 10.6 and 10.7. No fancy stuff like FileVault is active.

This does look like an OS bug to me, but I haven't found any mentions of this problem on the web.

Questions are:

1) Have you ever experienced something like this? Any findings?

2) What would be the steps to further diagnose this before using a tech support incident?

Comment: Uhm, it sounds like a conflict between your app and Dropbox. Note that Dropbox also uses FSEvents to watch the change inside the Dropbox folder.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround?  I see the same issue, and my theory is that dropbox's usage of FSEvents is blocking.  Interesting, because Google Drive has no such blocking issue.

Comment: Me too - but only for some users and also continues even when Dropbox is off.  Perhaps Dropbox leaves some meta data in there that by changing name of the folder gets invalidated

Comment: Similar thing happened to me. Instead of getting stuck completely, the monitored folder does send a notification _only with_ the `kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged` flag, even when the root itself is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known "FSEvents" bug in OS X.  It can create all sorts of problems that are hard to track down.  See [this page](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86239) for more information about the issue.  In particular, the page has a link to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/andreyvit/find-fsevents-bugs) with a utility to find all directories on your machine susceptible to the issue (which need not be in your DropBox folder).

Comment: Thank you, but I am in fact the author of those pages. :-) I have good news for you, though — Apple claims that it is fixed in 10.11.

Comment: See our discussion in rb-fsevents ticket for a lot more details and background (and a working workaround for pre-10.11!)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't look at the username before posting!  Otherwise, I wouldn't have posted.  I just filed two issues in your repo btw. Great job with it! :)

Comment: Hey @AndreyTarantsov, I am using Catalina and believe this bug is still occurring. Did Apple ever fix this?

Comment: @sunknudsen I believed it to be fixed on Catalina for sure. Does my tool (find-fsevents-bugs) flag the bug for you?