# NSRunLoop returns early, before any FSEvent or timer fires

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsthread, fsevents

I'm trying to use a NSRunLoop to watch for FSEvents in an Agent
application (that is, without any GUI).  I *think* I understand how a
RunLoop works, but I clearly don't, because the behaviour I'm seeing
is incomprehensible.  What am I missing?  (I'm comfortable with thread
programming in a few languages, but Objective-C is a bit of a novelty
for me).

Copied below is a (near as I can get it) minimal implementation of an
`EventHandler` class.  This is called from a main function by
allocating and initialising an instance, then sending that a
`startWatching` message with `"/tmp/fussybot-test"`, then finally `tidyUp`.

The implementation code below creates, schedules and starts an event stream attached
to the default RunLoop, then loops, waiting with `runMode:beforeDate`
on any FSEvents, or on the expiry of the RunLoop's timer.

```
#import "EventHandler.h"

void mycallback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                void *userData,
                size_t numEvents,
                void *eventPaths,
                const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{
    EventHandler *eh = (__bridge EventHandler*)userData;

    size_t i;
    char **paths = eventPaths;
    NSLog(@"callback: %zd events to process...", numEvents);
    for (i=0; i<numEvents; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Event %llu in %s (%x)", eventIds[i], paths[i], eventFlags[i]);
        [eh changedPath:paths[i]];
    }
}

@implementation EventHandler

-(void) startWatching: (NSString*) path
{
    NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [self createStream:path runLoop:theRL];

    BOOL recentFSActivity_p = YES;
    while (recentFSActivity_p) {

        NSDate* waitEnd = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5.0];
        //NSLog(@"waiting until %@", waitEnd); // XXX
        if (! [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                  beforeDate:waitEnd]) {
            NSLog(@"the run loop could not be started");
        }

        int ps = [self pathsSeen];
        NSLog(@"Main loop: pathsSeen=%i", ps);
        if (ps == 0) {
            recentFSActivity_p = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (void) tidyUp
{
    FSEventStreamStop(event_stream);
    FSEventStreamInvalidate(event_stream);
    return;
}


- (FSEventStreamRef) createStream: (NSString*) path
                          runLoop: (NSRunLoop*) theRL
{
    pathsToWatch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:path];
    FSEventStreamContext context = {0, (__bridge void*)self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFAbsoluteTime latency = 3.0; /* Latency in seconds */

    /* Create the stream, passing in a callback */
    event_stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                       &mycallback,
                                       &context,
                                       (__bridge CFArrayRef) pathsToWatch,
                                       kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow,
                                       latency,
                                       kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNone);

    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(event_stream,
                                     [theRL getCFRunLoop],
                                     kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    FSEventStreamStart(event_stream);

    return event_stream;
}

-(void)changedPath:(char *)path
{
    NSLog(@"Path %s changed", path); // log that we got here
    nchangedPaths += 1;              // ...and count the number of calls
}

-(int)pathsSeen
{
    int n = nchangedPaths;      // return instance variable
    nchangedPaths = 0;          // ...and reset it
    return n;
}
@end
```

OK, so we build that, start it going, and then touch a file in the
watched directory:

```
% make && ./fussybot & date '+NOW: %T'; sleep 2; echo hello >/tmp/fussybot-test/hello.txt
cc -c -x objective-c -fobjc-arc -o EventHandler.o EventHandler.m
cc -o fussybot main.o EventHandler.o -framework Cocoa
[1] 57431
NOW: 22:56:54
% 2013-04-22 22:56:57.692 fussybot[57431:707] callback: 1 events to process...
2013-04-22 22:56:57.694 fussybot[57431:707] Event 645428112 in /private/tmp/fussybot-test/ (11400)
2013-04-22 22:56:57.694 fussybot[57431:707] Path /private/tmp/fussybot-test/ changed
2013-04-22 22:56:57.695 fussybot[57431:707] Main loop: pathsSeen=1
2013-04-22 22:56:57.695 fussybot[57431:707] Main loop: pathsSeen=0
Exiting...

[1]  + done       ./fussybot
%
```

Then we *uncomment* the line `NSLog(@"waiting until %@", waitEnd);`
(marked with `XXX` above), and we try again:

```
% make && ./fussybot & date '+NOW: %T'; sleep 2; echo hello >/tmp/fussybot-test/hello.txt
cc -c -x objective-c -fobjc-arc -o EventHandler.o EventHandler.m
cc -o fussybot main.o EventHandler.o -framework Cocoa
[1] 57474
NOW: 22:59:01
2013-04-22 22:59:01.190 fussybot[57474:707] waiting until 2013-04-22 21:59:06 +0000
2013-04-22 22:59:01.190 fussybot[57474:707] Main loop: pathsSeen=0
Exiting...
[1]  + done       ./fussybot
%
```

There are now *two* extremely odd things here.

- First, adding an `NSLog` call changes the behaviour of the program.  Eh?!
- Secondly in both examples, the RunLoop appears to exit immediately, without waiting for an FSEvent.

Regarding the first, the fact that `NSLog` has an effect like that is
surely telling me something very important, but I can't for the life
of me work out what.

Regarding the second, in each of the `pathsSeen=0` cases, the
`runMode:beforeDate` message on the RunLoop object *does not block*,
but returns `YES`, even though the documentation for this message says
that it returns `YES` only “if the run loop ran and processed an input
source or if the specified timeout value was reached”, neither of
which is true in the `pathsSeen=0` cases above.  In each of those
cases I'd expect to see a 5s delay before the `pathsSeen=0` line
appears, as the RunLoop, not seeing any FSEvents, blocks to the end of
the `waitEnd` interval.

Both of these peculiarities suggest I'm misunderstanding something
pretty fundamental, presumably about object lifetimes.  I think I can
state each of the following:

- I am indeed expected to call `NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate` on the
  main thread of the program (the program doesn't have anything else
  to do whilst waiting, so being blocked is exactly the right
  thing).  This is compatible with the explanation of RunLoops in
  the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1).
- There's only one RunLoop per thread, so I *am* scheduling the
  `event_stream` on the RunLoop I'm waiting for.
- I own `event_stream`, by the Create Rule, so that's not being
  reclaimed behind my back.
- `waitEnd` will be different each time round the loop – ie, it's
  not preserved from pass to pass.
- Having `createStream:runLoop` initialise an *instance* variable
  `pathsToWatch` means I don't have to worry about this disappearing
  after `FSEventStreamCreate` has created the stream with this
  argument.  The ARC management would reclaim this at the end of the
  method if this were a local variable, but doesn't, because it's an
  instance variable.
- There are no other events which would cause the RunLoop to
  unblock.  Even if the OS did schedule something on this RunLoop
  (the documentation appears to carefully not rule that out), I'd
  see such an event in the callback.
- The `FSEventStreamEventFlags` on the event in the first case are expected ones –
  there's nothing to suggest that any events have been dropped for
  some reason.

That is, I appear to have proved that this cannot not work.  It
manifestly doesn't work, so ... what is it I'm catastrophically
failing to get? (and when I do get it, with a bang, is it going to
hurt?).

Does the FSEvent API represent a ‘port-based input source’, in the
terms of “The Run Loop Sequence of Events” within
the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1)?
If so, surely the FSEvent should be received in step 7 of that sequence.

The code above is closely based on the example code
in the [File System Events API
documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/FileSystemEvents/_index.html).
I think my understanding is compatible with the explanations in [this
thoughtful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092176/375147), but
I haven't been able to find many other relevant RunLoop questions.  The questions the SO system suggests are mostly to do with specifically adding NSTimers rather than using the RunLoop call's build-in timer.  [This question on FSEvent and Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841010/fsevents-mysteriously-fails-to-deliver-events-in-some-folders) looks likely, but (a) is unanswered, and (b) might be an interaction with Dropbox.

This is

```
% cc --version 
Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
```

on OS X 10.8.3.

(This is a long question: sorry.  Usually by the time you ask a
question this long, you've worked out the answer for yourself, but
– nope – I'm as puzzled now as I was before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The run loop is a shared resource. The frameworks can and do schedule their own run loop sources on the run loop, especially on the default mode. If `-runMode:beforeDate:` is returning `YES` and it didn't process one of your sources, then it presumably processed one scheduled by the frameworks.

If you want to run a run loop in a manner such that *only* your sources and timers will fire, then you need to schedule your sources and timers in a custom mode and run the run loop in that mode. A mode is effectively just a string, so use something like `@"com.yourcompany.yourproduct.yourmodename"` or something similarly guaranteed to be unique and you'll be fine.

Or you could simply write your code to cope with the fact that not all sources firing on the run loop will be yours.  If you want to detect expiration of a timeout, schedule a timer to set a flag and stop the run loop. Keep looping until the flag is set. I think you can use `CFRunLoopStop()` from your timer method to force `-runMode:beforeDate:` to return but, if not, you can use one of the `-performSelector...` methods that either take a thread or a delay to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. I thought I'd ruled out activity from other frameworks on the grounds that, if such activity happened, then my callback would hear about it. But is the real situation that that callback is invoked by the FSEvents event stream, which then (separately) delivers an event to the RunLoop which does nothing other than allow the RunLoop to exit? However the [FSEvents docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html) seem to say that the callback is received “from their runloop”. It probably doesn't matter, but...

Comment: And again...  I've amended my code so that it creates and schedules a timer in the default mode. I'm still uncertain, though, just who/where/what is firing my callback, but I'll let that go for the moment. That the run loop is shared, in the way you describe, is a pretty key bit of information that I would not have picked up from the NSRunLoop docs for a long time (I'm inclined to report a doc bug to the Apple bugparade). It's also amusing that the key features of a NSRunLoop are that it isn't a loop (it's called in a loop), and it doesn't run (it blocks). Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Added as issue 13719849 in the Apple bugparade (not that anyone outside Cupertino can see that...)

Comment: Each run loop source has a separate callback. Your callback only gets called when the FSEvents source has activity. The other sources (if any) call their own callbacks, which you obviously wouldn't see. For what it's worth, I expect that your callback is being called from the run loop, with a level of indirection. That is, your callback is not of the form required for a custom run loop source's perform callback, so clearly the FSEvents source has an internal callback informing it of activity and that calls your callback with appropriate arguments.